# sudo apt-get upgrade error E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: pantheon-terminal, kernel, updates

I've been getting an error when I try to run sudo apt-get upgrade. Can you help?

Thanks!

> :~$ sudo apt-get upgrade  Reading package lists... Done   Building
>   dependency tree          Reading state information... Done
>   Calculating upgrade... Done   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to
>   remove and 0 not upgraded.   3 not fully installed or removed.   After
>   this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.   Do you
>   want to continue? [Y/n] y   Setting up
>   linux-image-extra-4.4.0-36-generic (4.4.0-36.55~14.04.1) ...
>   run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal
>   4.4.0-36-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-36-generic   run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-36-generic
>   /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-36-generic   ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package
>   linux-headers-4.4.0-36-generic is not supported   Error! Bad return
>   status for module build on kernel: 4.4.0-36-generic (i686) Consult
>   /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.248+bdcom/build/make.log for more
>   information.   run-parts: executing
>   /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-36-generic
>   /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-36-generic   update-initramfs: Generating
>   /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-36-generic
>
> gzip: stdout: No space left on device   E: mkinitramfs failure cpio
>   141 gzip 1   update-initramfs: failed for
>   /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-36-generic with 1.   run-parts:
>   /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
>   dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-36-generic
>   (--configure):    subprocess installed post-installation script
>   returned error exit status 1 dpkg: dependency problems prevent
>   configuration of linux-image-generic-lts-xenial:
>   linux-image-generic-lts-xenial depends on
>   linux-image-extra-4.4.0-36-generic; however:   Package
>   linux-image-extra-4.4.0-36-generic is not configured yet.
>
> dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic-lts-xenial
>   (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg:
>   dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-lts-xenial:
>   linux-generic-lts-xenial depends on linux-image-generic-lts-xenial (=
>   4.4.0.36.26); however:   Package linux-image-generic-lts-xenial is not configured yet.
>
> dpkg: error processing package linux-generic-lts-xenial (--configure):
>   dependency problems - leaving unconfigured No apport report written
>   because the error message indicates its a followup error from a
>   previous failure.
>                                                                                                             No apport report written because the error message indicates its a
>   followup error from a previous failure.
>                                              Errors were encountered while processing:  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-36-generic 
>   linux-image-generic-lts-xenial  linux-generic-lts-xenial E:
>   Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: I'm on a 32bit version of Freya, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

So I found

```
sudo dpkg -l linux-* | awk '/^ii/{ print $2}' | grep -v -e `uname -r | cut -f1,2 -d"-"` | grep -e [0-9] | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
```

Works to remove all but the current version of the kernel and one backup.

I found the solution at the Ubuntu Stackexchange [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2262158&highlight=purge%20unused%20kernels).

I'm unhappy with how broad, sudden and irreversible the changes are, but no system of manual removal of specific kernel versions seemed to work.

This has tentatively provided a fix. I'll try keeping this updated if I encounter new problems.